# Why won't ASP.NET Web API deserialize this JSON object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, fiddler

My issue is to get my ASP.NET web API to deserialize the JSON data I provide in the request body, when calling the following controller on my API:

```
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<Notification> SearchNotifications(IEnumerable<SearchQuery> searchCriteria, int lastRow)
{
    INotificationService notificationService = new NotificationService();
    return notificationService.GetNotificationsFiltered(searchCriteria, User.UserData, lastRow);
}
```

The SearhQuery class looks like this:

```
public class SearchQuery
{
    public string Filter { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON data I provide in the request body (in Fiddler) looks like this:

```
{"searchCriteria":[{"filter":"category","value":"all_unread"}], "lastrow":60}
```

I get a 404: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this further??

Comment: A `404` response code isn't an issue with de/serialization. It means "[Not found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)." Or, that the path being requested isn't available for the method selected.

Comment: If it helps, the default route config for Web API's `ApiController`s doesn't include the `{action}` name (`routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"`). So, assuming a `SearchController`, the request would be to `POST /api/search`, unless you've customized the config.

Comment: Do you have a js fiddle I can adjust?  Web API expects two parameters to be posted separately, not in the same object. It's a 404 because web api thinks you are only sending one parameter which is also not type IEnumerable.

Comment: @Newse your comment sounds right. Unfortunately my API is not public, so you can't access anything there. Can you post a common example of separating parameters in JSON?